# Can't Put Newline in List Element Styled Using Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I am trying to put a newline inside of a list element styled using Bootstrap (not sure if this makes a difference). However, "\n" doesn't work and make a newline.

Here is my code:

```
var amountPrice = "Name: "+expenseName+"\n"+"Price: $"+expenseAmount
entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(amountPrice))
expensesList.appendChild(entry)
```

I'm creating a variable called Amount Price and setting it to two values that are, for example, "Apples" and "$5". I'm then adding that to an unordered list.

I do not get why my "\n" character is not making a newline where it should. Attached is a picture of the list. Sorry for my terrible photo editing.

[image: Picture of output]
Why is there no newline?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

What I believe you are referring to is the `<br />` tag.

A Newline character does not display a Newline when rendered as HTML apart from specific scenarios such as the content of a textbox.

You can also split each line of text to be contained within its own `p` tag:

```
<p>Name: item name</p>
<p>Price: $100</p>
```

Comment: Hi, I know this would work if I was using HTML, but I am rendering the list elements through javascript, so I'm not sure how I would do that while still maintaining the Name and Price values in the same list element,

Answer (score 0):

Well you should use

```html
<ul>
  <li id="amount"></li>
  <li id="price"></li>
</ul>
```

in your display page and render data to each li according to ther li ids..
I hope it will help you.